# MongoDB partial match on object

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to write a query in MongoDB to pull out certain objects based on whether a field partially matches a given object.

The objects in my MongoDB collection look something similar to this:

```
  {
    permissions: {
      records: [
        "add",
      ]
    }
  }
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the relevant objects by querying on the permissions of a given user.

For example, if I queried with the following object:

```
  {
    permissions: {
      records: [
        "add",
        "delete"
      ],
      folders: [
        "delete",
      ]
    }
  }
```

I'd want to return back the objects from the collection that partially matched the queried object, which would perhaps be these:

```
  {
    permissions: {
      records: [
        "add",
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    permissions: {
      records: [
        "delete",
      ],
      folders: [
        "delete",
      ]
    }
  }
```

If anyone could give me any guidance on this, that'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
db.tutorials.find({
    $or: [
        { "permissions.records": { $elemMatch: { $in: ["add", "delete"] } } },
        { "permissions.folders": { $elemMatch: { $in: ["delete"] } } },
        { "permissions.logs": { $elemMatch: { $in: ["add", "delete"] } } },
        { "permissions" : { $exists: false}}
    ]
})
```